# Оптимизация кода написанного с использованием Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, best-practice

Ниже приведен рабочий и корректный код. 
Меня интересует на сколько его еще можно оптимизировать по объему кода использую best practice при работе с pandas dataframe.

Суть решаемой задачи. 
Приведенный код генерирует все возможные комбинации для лотореи 6x36. 
Из сгенерированных комбинаций, мы последовательно исключаем комбинации для которых выполняется условие - остаток от деления 2 для всех значений шести шаров одной игры одинаковый. Такую же операцию делаем для деления на 3 и на 5

```
Например:
{1,3,5,7,9,11}%2 = {1,1,1,1,1,1} - исключаем, поскольку остаток от деления на 2 для всех значений шаров равен 1. 
{3,6,9,12,15,18}%3 = {0,0,0,0,0,0} - исключаем, поскольку остаток от деления на 3 для всех значений шаров равен 0


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
from itertools import combinations 
a = np.arange(1,37)
c = combinations(a, 6) 
df = pd.DataFrame(list(c))

r2 = df.apply(lambda x: x%2).stack().reset_index()
r3 = df.apply(lambda x: x%3).stack().reset_index()
r5 = df.apply(lambda x: x%5).stack().reset_index()

f2 = r2.groupby([r2.columns[0], r2.columns[2]]).agg(['count'])
z2 = f2[f2.values == 6].reset_index().level_0

f3 = r3.groupby([r3.columns[0], r3.columns[2]]).agg(['count'])
z3 = f3[f3.values == 6].reset_index().level_0

f5 = r5.groupby([r5.columns[0], r5.columns[2]]).agg(['count'])
z5 = f5[f5.values == 6].reset_index().level_0

z = pd.concat([z2,z3,z5], axis=0, join='outer', join_axes=None, ignore_index=False,
          keys=None, levels=None, names=None, verify_integrity=False,
          copy=True)

s = df[~df.index.isin(z)]
print(s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
In [16]: def modulo_all(df, num):
    ...:     a = (df % num).values
    ...:     return (a == a[:, [0]]).all(axis=1)
    ...:

In [17]: mask2 = df.pipe(modulo_all, 2)

In [18]: mask3 = df.pipe(modulo_all, 3)

In [19]: mask5 = df.pipe(modulo_all, 5)

In [20]: res = df[~(mask2 | mask3 | mask5)]

In [21]: res.shape
Out[21]: (1907842, 6)
```